# Images takes much time to load in asp repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a repeater in which I place `<asp:Image>` in which

ImageUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Path") %>'

`Path` in the `Container.Dataitem` is the URL of the images which shown in repeater and URL makes a string with the help of select query

There will be almost 140 images which will be load in asp repeater and it takes 20 second to load all images ..but my requirement is to manage it to 5 to 6 seconds...

Do you guys have any solution

Comment: Would deferred execution of the image loading help? So the page can fully render and then you start rendering images individually after that? Overall page time might be the same but it might be more usable... Are the images static or dynamically generated? Where is the actual bottleneck in the process?

Comment: What about image sizes (kb, mb)?

Comment: images are dynamically generated

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading them directly, you could use AJAX to load them one at a time. You can then control the order in which they are loaded (eg load top 10 first, then load next 10). Similar to how Facebook does photo uploads. It doesn't try and upload them all at once. You could even go so far as loading them first as small low res versions (to make it look like its done), then load the high res ones on top of them.

Comment: @user3091060 any one you want. I personally prefer jQuery (see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ or http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ or http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: I used lazy load ,,well it's work only in div...but when i put a div in asp panel..lazy loading is not working..i mean it shows image normally without any effect..help...